# Is there a limit to the number of HStacks in a List (SwiftUI)?

Tags: swift, listview, swiftui

I have a List in SwiftUI that I use to display my view model.  Oddly, when I specify the last HStack in my List, the view no longer compiles. The following compiles and works correctly:

```
struct LandingResultView: View {
    @Binding var dryLand: LandingViewModel
    @Binding var wetLand: LandingViewModel

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            List {
                HStack {
                    Text("30T")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.2)
                    Text("\(self.dryLand.throttles30)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                    Text("\(self.wetLand.throttles30)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("10T")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.2)
                    Text("\(self.dryLand.throttles10)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                    Text("\(self.wetLand.throttles10)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("0T")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.2)
                    Text("\(self.dryLand.throttles0)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                    Text("\(self.wetLand.throttles0)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("30F")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.2)
                    Text("\(self.dryLand.flaps30)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                    Text("\(self.wetLand.flaps30)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("10F")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.2)
                    Text("\(self.dryLand.flaps10)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                    Text("\(self.wetLand.flaps10)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("0F")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.2)
                    Text("\(self.dryLand.flaps0)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                    Text("\(self.wetLand.flaps0)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Land 30")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.2)
                    Text("\(self.dryLand.landing30)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                    Text("\(self.wetLand.landing30)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Land 10")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.2)
                    Text("\(self.dryLand.landing10)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                    Text("\(self.wetLand.landing10)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Land 0")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.2)
                    Text("\(self.dryLand.landing0)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                    Text("\(self.wetLand.landing0)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("HB")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.2)
                    Text("\(self.dryLand.hb)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.6)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following, does not compile and will not render.  I know SwiftUI is finicky, but I cannot see where I am going wrong here:

```
struct LandingResultView: View {
    @Binding var dryLand: LandingViewModel
    @Binding var wetLand: LandingViewModel

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            List {
                HStack {
                    Text("30T")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.2)
                    Text("\(self.dryLand.throttles30)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                    Text("\(self.wetLand.throttles30)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("10T")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.2)
                    Text("\(self.dryLand.throttles10)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                    Text("\(self.wetLand.throttles10)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("0T")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.2)
                    Text("\(self.dryLand.throttles0)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                    Text("\(self.wetLand.throttles0)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("30F")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.2)
                    Text("\(self.dryLand.flaps30)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                    Text("\(self.wetLand.flaps30)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("10F")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.2)
                    Text("\(self.dryLand.flaps10)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                    Text("\(self.wetLand.flaps10)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("0F")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.2)
                    Text("\(self.dryLand.flaps0)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                    Text("\(self.wetLand.flaps0)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Land 30")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.2)
                    Text("\(self.dryLand.landing30)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                    Text("\(self.wetLand.landing30)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Land 10")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.2)
                    Text("\(self.dryLand.landing10)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                    Text("\(self.wetLand.landing10)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Land 0")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.2)
                    Text("\(self.dryLand.landing0)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                    Text("\(self.wetLand.landing0)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.3)
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("HB")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.2)
                    Text("\(self.dryLand.hb)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.6)
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("HB")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.2)
                    Text("\(self.dryLand.hb)")
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.6)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I intentionally repeated the last `HStack` to rule out any potential issues with what I was displaying.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10, try using Group to split them in groups of 10.

Comment: Can you use Group within a List? I looked into the documentation more and you are correct that 10 is the magic limit.

Comment: 10 is the limit for everything. :) That is _why_ Group exists.